# ASP.NET friendly image editor

Tags: asp.net, flash, silverlight, image-processing

I'm looking for an image editor that I can embed easily into an ASP.NET website. I need to be able to draw rectangles, lines and add some text. Additionally, images must not be uploaded to third-party servers.

I've checked sites of the main ISVs that develop .NET controls but none of them provides a standalone image editor that offers all the functionally I mentioned. Most of them let you rotate, flip, resize images and set some filters, that's it. There is one editor http://pixlr.com/app/) that is nearly there. Unfortunately all images have to be uploaded to Pixlr servers which is a deal breaker from my perspective. It can bee anything (JavaScript, Flash, Silverlight, etc) that integrates with ASP.NET.

thanks

Pawel

Answer (score 3):

I think [AtalaSoft](http://www.atalasoft.com/products/dotimage/thinclient/default.aspx) has and editor that will do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (sense == 1) //Rotate 90 to right
    {
        img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate270FlipXY);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

By 'image editor', do you mean photo editor or drawing application? (Sorry, the 'draw lines and rectangles' thing threw me a little) There's a Silverlight-based photo editor (with text adding capabilities) at http://imago.konnektion.com which can be integrated as an ASP.NET control or directly through HTML code on any web page, with configurable upload destination address - is that something like what you had in mind?