# I would like to rotate images on the web using aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, image

I am writing an application ( .NET 4.0 using web forms).  What I like to do is to give the ability for users to see images they have stored in a directory and be able to perform changes to their pictures ( zoom, rotate, crop, etc).  I can do the zoom, rotate and crop in winforms, but I can't figure out how to display it in aspx without saving it.

so imagine image A displayed in an image control.  User clicks on it to zoom.  I pass it to a method.  it rotates.  But how do I redisplay it rotated?  Do I have to save the image and then display it?  Maybe I am going about this all wrong.  Does someone have a sample code to accomplish this?  Sample code to display an image on an aspx and rotate and show the rotated image.

Thanks

Comment: I tried the basic of placing an Web Controls image on the form.  But I am not that strong with aspx, specially with images.  I am just asking for help

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/hrojasara/how-to-rotate-images-in-Asp-Net/

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this link will point you in the right direction. [ASP.NET friendly image editor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/314958/asp-net-friendly-image-editor)

Win and web forms are 2 totally different beasts, and short of saving it to the sever on each and every change, you'd really want to have the client handle most of the work until they hit save.